# Can one take roots of rank-into-rank embeddings infinitely many times?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

If $\lambda$ is a cardinal, then let $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$ be the set of all elementary embeddings from $V_{\lambda}$ to $V_{\lambda}$. If $j,k\in\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$, then define $j*k=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}j(k|_{V_{\alpha}})$. Then $j*k\in\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$. Therefore the set $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$ becomes an algebra with operations $*$ and composition $\circ$.

Is it possible that there exists a sequence $(j_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ in $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}\setminus\{\textrm{Id}_{V_{\lambda}}\}$ (here $\textrm{Id}_{V_{\lambda}}$ is the identity mapping) along with a sequence $(t_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ of term functions in the language with function symbols $*,\circ$ such that $t_{n}(j_{n+1})*j_{n+1}=j_{n}$ for all $n\in\omega$? Is it still possible if we let each $t_{n}$ be the same term or if we let the set $\{t_{n}|n\in\omega\}$ be finite?

It seems like it is impossible for there to be such a descending sequence $(j_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ since it seems like the large cardinal hypotheses satisfied by $j_{n}$ become weaker and weaker as $n\rightarrow\omega$. For instance, if we let $t_{n}$ be the identity term function for all $n$, then $j_{n+1}*j_{n+1}=j_{n}$ for all $n\in\omega$. However, this implies that $\textrm{crit}(j_{n})=\textrm{crit}(j_{n+1}*j_{n+1})=j_{n+1}(\textrm{crit}(j_{n+1}))>\textrm{crit}(j_{n+1})$ which contradicts the well-foundedness of the ordinals (here we used the fact that $\textrm{crit}(j*k)=j(\textrm{crit}(k))$).

Comment: I guess you want to consider only nontrivial elementary embeddings. Otherwise, $id(id)*id=id$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @Jospeh Van Name I have nothing to add, but I suspect Prof. Scott Cramer at Rutgers could share some insight [link](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~ssc127/papers.html). His papers on Inverse Limits and the various reflections possible using them seems very relevant. ~~~~